# How to use numpy.ndarray to slice a pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray

I have pandas frame `F` and numpy ndarray `a`, of dimensions m x n and m x 1 respectively. `a` contains only 1's and 0's and I'm trying to get a new pandas frame that are the rows of `F` for which `a` is 1.

I tried `F2 = F[a,:]` and `F2 = F[a.tolist(),:]`, neither of which was successful. How do I tackle this please?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Your answer was good, and exactly what I needed. I just haven't gotten around (until now) to wrap this question up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, going for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` should do:

```
F.loc[a.astype(bool)]
```